# IIS Url Rewrite for Blue/Green deployment

Tags: iis, rewrite, deployment

I am following Kevin Reeds tutorial on [How to Deploy Anything in IIS with Zero Downtime on a Single Server](https://kevinareed.com/2015/11/07/how-to-deploy-anything-in-iis-with-zero-downtime-on-a-single-server/). Right now I am just trying to get it to work on my local machine, before trying to apply the same approach on some of the websites at work.

So far I have:

- Set up two sites in IIS; `alwaysup-blue` on port 8001 and `alwaysup-green` on port 8002
- Added entries to the HOSTS file for `alwaysup`, `alwaysup-blue` and `alwaysup-green`, all pointing to 127.0.0.1
- Added a Server farm in IIS, and added the two sites to the farm.
- Added the health checks to the serverfarm, using the `up.html` approach, described in the article.
- Set up an inboud URL Rewrite rule, to direct any requests for "alwaysup" to the Server farm.

I can request the blue and green sites individually. The health checks for the web farm seem to be working, so when I edit one from "down" to "up", it becomes healthy, and vice versa.

The problem is I get a 404, when requesting http://alwaysup, so I suspect the problem is in the URL Rewrite rule. I have inspected the `applicationHost.config` file for IIS, and the rule has the same contents as in Kevin's article.

How do I figure out what is wrong? How can I check if the URL Rewrite Rule is "hit" or not?

IIS version is 7.5.7600.16385. I have installed ARR using a [standalone package installer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47332).